# How to perform two different types of action after successful service call NGRX

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs6, ngrx-effects

So I have a product search effect. Basically I first dispatch a search_start action, which has a payload of parameters for that search, The effect takes that then goes to a service and I get that response back, which gives me a list of products. I want to be able to then do two things:

1. Dispatch a successful action with the collection of products
2. Save the parameters for that search to be used later for 'search history' which is currently in the 'action.payload'

I'm having a problem the 2nd piece mainly because doing switchMap and having a returnType of 'SearchResultResponseType' means that I can't now do a SearchSave(action.payload) mainly because the payload has the type of 'SearchParameterType'. So I can only execute my SearchSuccess action.

Is there anyway this can be accomplished? I tried changing the response type to a super type that takes both SearchParameterType and SearchResultResponseType as two properties on that type and having my productSearchService return that instead but that seemed to yield errors as well. Isn't there a simper way?

```
       export class ProductSearchEffects {
          @Effect() startSearch$: Observable<
            ActionWithPayload<SearchResultResponseType> | Observable<Action>
          > = this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType<SearchStart>(ProductSearchActions.SEARCH_START),
            mergeMap(action =>
              this.productSearchService.fetchSearchResults(action.payload)
                .pipe(
// if successful then save search and dispatch search success
                switchMap((data: SearchResultResponseType) => [
                    new SearchSave(action.payload),
                    new SearchSuccess(data),
                  ]),

                  catchError(() => of(new SearchFail())),
                ),
            ),
          );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common practice I've seen and personally adopted is to alias your actions, i.e., `type SearchAction = SearchStart | SearchSave | SearchSuccess | SearchFail'` and then the return type of your effect is `Observable<SearchAction>`. TypeScript will then verify that all actions being returned are covered by the alias.

Comment: Agree and this is as it should be. it will also keep everything strongly typed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to explicitly define the return type.
You can do it with `mergeMap` otherwise. I see you put your `switchMap` and `mergeMap` in reverse, you just need to reverse the position and you should be good to go.

```
export class ProductSearchEffects {
          @Effect() startSearch$ = this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType<SearchStart>(ProductSearchActions.SEARCH_START),
            switchMap(action =>
              this.productSearchService.fetchSearchResults(action.payload)
                .pipe(
                  mergeMap((data: SearchResultResponseType) => [
                    new SearchSave(action.payload),
                    new SearchSuccess(data),
                  ]),
                  catchError(() => of(new SearchFail())),
                ),
            ),
          );
```

Comment: This works, but what i'm asking is there a way to have this done AND it be strongly typed? I want to follow best practices and that would be keeping everything typed

Comment: I think for effects, there is no need for it to be strongly-typed because it has no benefits at all since we are not able to tap directly into effects. But if you really want to do so, the best option is to chain your call with another effect that is listening to one of the action you dispatch in the startSearch$ effect